# I need to show a 1 post excerpt in the home page from several custom post types and no matter what i do i get all of them instead of 1

Tags: wordpress

I am very sorry for being dumb, but for the life of me i dont understand here is my code

```
<div class="korobka1">
            <?php 
             $args = array(
              'post_type' => 'poetrys',
              'posts_per_page' => '-1',
                 );

             $blogposts = new WP_Query($args);

             while($blogposts->have_posts()) {
                   $blogposts->the_post();
               ?>
            <div class="image">
                <a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <img src= "<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID()); ?>" alt="Card Image">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="card-description">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                </a>
                <div class="short-info"><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_excerpt(), 30); ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" >Read more</a>
                </div>
                
            </div>
            
            <?php }
            wp_reset_query(); ?>

        </div>
```

Like this i have 10 custom types they all go in their own divs on the home page, i tryed changing to 1, -1, '1' '-1' and nothing seams to be working instead it is returning all the post from specific categore instead of just one Please please help me!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: You question isn’t very clear. You say you want 1 post on the homepage from several CPTs but you only mention one CPT. Do mean you want *several* posts on the home page but only one from each CPT? Also you said “i tryed changing to 1, -1, '1' '-1'...” - *what* did you try changing to this? I assume you mean `posts_per_page`? This should be `1` or `’1’`... -1 means get *ALL* posts.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what i mean i have 10 CPT's each and everyone of them will have many posts but i want to output 1 newest post from each of them on a home page,the code is identical for them all i am changing is the name of each CPT, i have tried formatting code every way i mentioned including 1 or '1' with comma at the end and without i even tried to put 2 posts to see if this works at all and it only returns all of them